# how to set up a legend in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I use the graph from highcharts and want the legends to be displayed in several lines relative to the graph. How to arrange the elements of the legend in several lines?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set the legend items in several lines, you can use the `legend.width` and `legend.itemWidth` properties of the legend object.

```
legend: {
    width: 300, // set the maximum width of the legend container
    itemWidth: 150 // set the width of each legend item
},
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2d9sqr4c/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.width 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemWidth